# Convert text syntax into PHP statement

Tags: php

It's little difficult to explain it but if you can't get it please do not vote down !
I built a survey system and my question are from the DB. I want to validate them dynamically so I thought about it :

```
$query = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM radio');
$issetradio = '';
while($row = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $issetradio .= '&&isset($_POST["'.$row['value'].'"])';
}
$issetradio = substr($issetradio,2); // returns "isset($_POST['1']) && isset($_POST['2'])"
```

Now I want this $issetradio to be in if statement for validation, I want it to be:

```
if(isset($_POST['1']) && isset($_POST['2']))
```

The problem is that the $issetradio is in text syntax and it inputs like that :

```
if($issetradio) // if('isset(['1']) && isset([''])')
```

Thank You All !

Comment: why this way? any idea?

Comment: why are you putting the php code in to a variable? i would be storing `$row['value']` in an array and loop through it for validation at the latter point.

Comment: Hi !
I'm new developer and my ways of thinking maybe not good because im not experienced, I'll be thankful if you suggest me better way.

Comment: @Dagon I can't put the While loop into the if so I thought put into variable is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it won't work like that (you could probably use `eval()` for this but don't do it!)

just use simple loop and additional variable:

```
$query = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM radio');
$ok=true;
while($row = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       if(!isset($_POST["'.$row['value'].'"]))
          $ok=false;
}
if($ok) {...}
```